# JavaScript Error Message when adding Milliseconds to a clock

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

when adding milliseconds to a clock. I am copying it out of a book, so I am not sure what is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Event Test</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            now = new Date();
            localtime = now.toString();
            utctime = now.toGMTString();
            document.write("<strong>Local time:</strong> " 
            + localtime + "<br/>");
            document.write("<strong>UTC time:</strong> " +
            utctime);
            hours = now.getHours();
            minutes = now.getMinutes();
            seconds = now.getSeconds();
            mil = now.getMilliseconds();
            document.write("<h1>");
            document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" mil);
            document.write("</h1>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing a `+` here:

```
 document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" mil);
//--------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" mil);
```

should read

```
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + mil);
```

There is a `+` missing before `mil`

Answer (score 1):

you missed a +

```
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + mil);
```